# Como faço para alterar o grupo de autorização de uma tela de geração de tabelas?

Tags: erp, abap

Quero trocar o "grupo autorizações", porém não consigo editar uma tela já construída.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para alterar o grupo de autorização, basta seguir os seguintes passos:

1. Chamar transação se11
2. após a abertura é necessário passar o nome da tabela e clicar em modificar.
3. em seguida, entre na opção utilitários(menu superior) > gerador de atualização de tabela
4. troque o grupo de autorização e clique em salvar.

Somente com esses passos é possível alterá-lo.